# javascript typing across multiple textbox

Tags: javascript

I need help with my javascript code, I have 3 text boxes with character counter below them counting from 4 to 0. I used 2 functions for this, the 1st function is for the counter, the 2nd function moves the focus of the cursor to the next textbox once counter hits 0. functions shown below.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var maxAmount = 4;
function textCounter(textField, showCountField) {
if (textField.value.length > maxAmount) {
textField.value = textField.value.substring(0, maxAmount);
} else { 
showCountField.value = maxAmount - textField.value.length;}}

function moveCursor(fromTextBox, toTextBox){
var length = fromTextBox.value.length;
var maxLength = fromTextBox.getAttribute("maxLength");
if (length == maxLength){
document.getElementById(toTextBox).focus ();}}
```

and this is how my text areas where coded, shown below

```
<textarea name="ta" id="ta1" rows="7" style="width:340px;"  MaxLength="4" 
onKeyDown="textCounte(this.form.ta,this.form.countDisplay);"
oninput="textCounter(this.form.ta,this.form.countDisplay); 
moveCursor(this,'ta2')" ></textarea>
<br>
<input readonly tabindex="-1" type="text" name="countDisplay" size="3" 
maxlength="3" value="4" style="border: none;">
```

below is the sample output:

[image]

What I want to happen is if I type 4 characters in the first textarea example "1234" then instead of continuously typing to the 2nd textarea, I decided to click on the first textarea to set focus at the beginning and type in 4 characters example "4321", i want the original contents of the first text area pushed to the second text area. example result : [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5Sf4.jpg)

And if i do the same and type in 1234 again on the first textarea, the original contents of textarea1 will be pushed to textarea2 and textarea2's contents to textarea 3: [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sGUN.jpg)

thank you.

Comment: Like a credit card number?

Comment: You want same text in all textarea??

Comment: Post a [mcve] please.

Comment: Yes it works like a credit card number, when I type 4 characters in the first textbox, the cursor moves to the next textbox, and the same happens when i type 4 characters on the second textbox focus moves to third textbox.

Comment: My problem is that, when I decide not to  continue typing in the succeeding txtarea and go back to the very first txtarea to type another 4 characters, i want the original content of the first txtarea to be pushed to the next txtarea.